# DateTime Array with get set in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, get, set

I have the following code. Would anyone tell me if this is correct according to C# rules.

```
public DateTime[] datetime = new DateTime[];
```

I am unable to use get; set with the above.

And subsequently, I want to save dates to datetime.

How to do it?

Comment: In C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015, or 2013 with Roslyn), the following statement will be supported:
`public DateTime[] datetime { get; set; } = new DateTime[4];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would anyone tell me if this is correct according to C# rules.

I'm not sure what you mean by rules. But, according to the C# specification, you have to specify the size of the array when declaring it:

```
public DateTime[] datetime = new DateTime[5];
```

> I am unable to use get; set with the above.

Because that isn't the correct syntax for declaring a *property*. You do it like this:

```
public DateTime[] DateTimes { get; set; }
```

And you initialize it via a constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        DateTimes = new DateTime[5];
    }

    public DateTime[] DateTimes { get; set; }
}
```

Which will now give you an array with 5 elements

Note that if you know the amount of dates beforehand, you can use array initializer syntax as well:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        DateTimes = { new DateTime(1, 1, 1970), new DateTime(2, 1, 1980) };
    }

    public DateTime[] DateTimes { get; set; }
}
```

If the array size isn't known beforehand, you should perhaps consider using a `List<DateTime>` which can be expanded at runtime.

Comment: By  rules, I simply meant according to th Syntax of CSharp. Sorry for th confusion. I will try the sample replies and subsequently report.

Comment: Thank you to UncleDave and Yuvalltzhakov. My problem is solved by using the code they have shown. It works correctly now.

Comment: I will never write Csharp again in place of C#. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think we need to be quite so pedantic, +1 for your reply Unnikrishnan

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare and initialise a property at the same time, unlike with a field. Instead initialise it in your class' constructor:

```
public DateTime[] datetime { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
  datetime = new DateTime[];
}
```

If your array is not a fixed size and you'll be adding an unknown amount of dates to it, consider using a List instead:

```
public List<DateTime> datetime { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
  datetime = new List<DateTime>();

  // Add a DateTime:
  var newDateTime = DateTime.Now;
  datetime.Add(newDateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you UncleDave.  I will try to implement you suggestion. and report the success of it later.